# Bash - How do I redirect stderr to the stdout of the next command in a pipe line?

Tags: bash

Context: I have a backup script that tars a specified directory then pipes it to gpg to symmetrically encrypt and compress the archive. I then redirect stderr to stdout and pipe both to `tee` to log it to a file and save the output to a shell variable.

```
RESULT=$(tar -c "$BACKUPPATH" |
         gpg --batch --passphrase 1234 --yes \
             -o "$FILELOC" -c --bzip2-compress-level 9 \
             2>&1 |
         tee -a "$LOG")
```

However, tar has been failing, so I want to capture tar's stderr in the same manner (so it shows up in `$RESULT` and also in the log file).

What's the best way to do this?

I tried this:

```
RESULT=$(tar -c "$BACKUPPATH" 3<&2 |
         gpg --cipher-algo AES256 --batch --passphrase 1234 --yes \
             -o "$FILELOC" -c --bzip2-compress-level 9 \
             2>&1 3>&1 |
         tee -a  "$LOG");
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I pass a bogus path to tar. It doesn't show up in the log or variable. Maybe I need a fifo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RESULT=$(
    {
        tar -c "$BACKUPPATH" |
        gpg --batch --passphrase 1234 --yes \
            -o "$FILELOC" -c --bzip2-compress-level 9; \
    } 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG"
)
```

Redirect the stderr of both commands by putting them inside curly braces and having the `2>&1` redirection apply to the whole compound command.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why my solution didn't work? Does the file descriptor not persist past the pipe?

Comment: `3<&2` treats stderr like an input source rather than an output source. `<` is only for stdin. And yes, the redirection doesn't affect other commands as written.

Comment: A pipe passes stdout of one command to stdin of another; it doesn't connect up/pass through/etc *any* of their other file descriptors.